# FFT by parts in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, fft, web-audio-api

I'm using Web Audio Api to get the frequency of the dominant note which I get through a microphone.
The problem is that if I use a too-big fft, the program can't compute it, and if I use a small fft the lower frequencies cannot be correctly computed.

So I guess the solution is to do my own algorithm for the fft by parts.
However, to do that I have to treat directly the values of the ScriptProcessor buffer. Can someone tell me what are this values? I also need to know if the ScriptProcessos buffer size matters to get a good result.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: I'd be surprised if the built-in fft is less efficient than one you could code in Javascript, since you don't have control over caching, threading or vectorisation. How big are you trying to make the buffer? And have you considered down-sampling first (reducing the sample rate), since you're only looking for low-frequencies? If you want frequencies around the 10s of Hz or less, you'll certainly be better-off by downsampling first.

Comment: You can reduce the computation time by either i) downsampling your data so you work wit fewer samples and you are only working with frequencies of interest or ii) reducing the number of points in your FFT (this will reduce the resolution in the frequency domain).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I've been looking for a way to reduce the AudioContext.sampleRate but it seems impossible. Do you know how to do that??